# C++ Program is printing memory address and not value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototype
void popCalculator(int &, int &, double &, double &);
void popFinder(int &, int &, int &, double &, double &);

int popArray[101];

int main()
{

    int startingPop;
    int population;
    double birthRate;
    double deathRate;
    int numYears;

    // These are the prompts for the user to enter the starting population,
    // the annual birth rate, the annual death rate, and the number of years.
    // Birth rate and death rate need to be entered as decimals.

    cout << "This program calculates population change.\n";

    // This is where you enter the starting population size and the annual birth
    // rate. If the starting population is less than two, you have to enter
    // a new starting population. Likewise, if the birth rate percent is
    // less than 0, you have to enter a new one.

    cout << "Enter the starting population size: Enter the annual birth rate" <<
              "(as % of current population: ";
    cin >> startingPop;
    while (startingPop < 2)
    {
        cout << "Please re-enter: Starting population must be 2 or more.";
        cin >> population;
    }
    cin >> birthRate;
    while (birthRate < 0)
    {
        cout << "Birth rate percent cannot be negative.\n";
        cout << "Please re-enter: ";
        cin >> birthRate;
    }

    // This is where you enter the annual death rate population.
    // If the death rate percent is less than 0, you have to enter a new one.

    cout << "Enter the annual death rate (as % of current population): ";
    cin >> deathRate;
    while (deathRate < 0)
    {
        cout << "Death rate percent cannot be negative.\n";
        cout << "Please re-enter: ";
        cin >> deathRate;
    }

    // This is where you enter the number of years to view the population
    // changes over. The number can't be less than zero or greater than 100
    // and you will be prompted to enter a new one if the number falls
    // in either of those categories.

    cout << "For how many years do you wish to view population changes? ";
    cin >> numYears;
    while (numYears < 0 || numYears > 100)
    {
        cout << "Years must be one or more, but less than or equal to 100.\n";
        cout << "Please re-enter: ";
        cin >> numYears;
    }

    // This prints out what the starting population is before the program
    // prints out the rest of the population listings

    cout << "Starting population: " << startingPop << endl << endl;
    popFinder(startingPop, population, numYears, birthRate, deathRate);
}

void popCalculator(int &startingPop, int &population, double &birthRate, double &deathRate)
{
    population = startingPop + (startingPop * birthRate) - (startingPop * deathRate);
    population = population + (population * birthRate) - (population * deathRate);
}

void popFinder(int &startingPop, int &population, int &numYears, double &birthRate, double &deathRate)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= numYears; i++)
    {
        popArray[] = population;
        if (population < 0)
        {
            population = 0;
            cout << "Population at the end of year " << i << " is " << static_cast<int>(population);
        }
        cout << "Population at the end of year " << i << " is " << static_cast<int>(population) << endl;
    }
}
```

That's my code so far, what I'm figuring to be nearly done. The idea behind the program is to take in values for starting population, birth rate, death rate, and number of years, calculate the population over the set of years, store those values in an array, and print that out. My main issue right now, is that I seem to be printing out what I'm assuming is the memory address and not the values. I feel like I'm coming close to figuring this out, but this part has me absolutely stumped and I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Please narrow it down. From the sounds of it you should be able to reproduce the problem with a 3-5 line program. You don't need all of this to reproduce it.

Comment: And I have no idea what `popArray[] = population;` is supposed to do. C++ isn't PHP.

Comment: population is already an int. why do you do static_cast ?

Comment: How are you getting the wrong values printed out with code that won't even compile. `popArray[] = population;` is not valid.

Comment: There are lots of `cout` statements. Which ones are printing the addresses instead of values?

Comment: "population" is never initialized, so the value you are printing it whatever happens to be on the stack. *Always* initialize your local variables - it will save you immeasurable grief. int population = 0;

Comment: I recognize this code, like it was in another SO question a week ago...